# sort elements in NSArray based on timestamp of element in my case

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I have an array of `NSString`, each `NSString` element contains a timestamp (epoch time) and other characters, e.g.: `"time:1474437948687, <other characters>"`.

```
NSArrary *myData = [self loadData];// my array
```

So, `myData` looks like this inside:

```
{"time:1474437948687,fajlsfj...",
 "time:1474237943221, axsasdfd...",
 "time:1474681430940, someother...",
 ...
}
```

I need to have an array which contains the same elements as the above array, but are sorted in descending order of the timestamp. How can I do it?

I get stuck with iterating over the array of NSString:

```
for (NSString element in myData) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Use NSSortDescriptor to short an array based on time.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at NSSortDescriptor soon, I haven't used it before.

Comment: can you show ur array

Comment: @Leem.fin pl. check my answer I was update sorting with primitives type on same day..

Answer (score -1):

Use following **sortedArrayUsingComparator** it will work for me : I use static data e.g  time:1474437948687, ..

```
**time:1474437948687, <other characters> Consider String Format..**

    NSArrary *myData = [self loadData];
    NSArrary *sortedmyData = [[myData sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        // Change Date formate accordingly ====
        [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
        NSDate *d1 = [df dateFromString:[self sperateDate:obj1]];
        NSDate *d2 = [df dateFromString:[self sperateDate:obj2]];
        return [d1 compare: d2];
    }];
```

// This is function is developed as per  **time:1474437948687,  Consider String Format..**

```
- (NSString *)sperateDate : (NSString *)obj1 {
    NSArray *arr = [obj1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSArray *arr1 = [arr[0] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    return arr1[1];
}
```

**Update Compare with primitive type :**

```
    NSArray *myData = @[@"time:1474437948687,fajlsfj...",@"time:1474237943221, axsasdfd...",@"time:1474681430940, someother..."
    NSArray *sortedmyData = [myData sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSNumber *d1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[self sperateDate:obj1] doubleValue]];
    NSNumber *d2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[self sperateDate:obj2] doubleValue]];
    return [d1 compare: d2];
    }];
```

Hope this help you...

Do let me know if you have any other query

Comment: Thanks, I am trying it now, will let you know the result.

Comment: Can we just use the epoch time in milliseconds to do the comparison instead of converting to NSDate?

Comment: still I am looking... dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 will give milliseconds from 1970. with both the object so need to compare milliseconds given by both objects. It may not solve purpose of compare two date and sorting...

Comment: if you want to convert epoch to date with seconds then we can use different date formatter. e.g [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy H:mm:ss"];

Comment: I managed solve this issue by converting to NSNumber, and compare the NSNumber objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123834/discussion-between-ketan-p-and-leem-fin).

Comment: we can compare it with any primitive types which allows for easy use of '>' '<' '==' etc

Comment: Could you please update your answer to use primitives to do the comparison & then, I will accept your answer :)

Comment: @Leem.fin Update answer with primitives type.. Its give below result (
time:1474237943221, axsasdfd...,
time:1474437948687,fajlsfj...,
time:1474681430940, someother...
)

Comment: @Leem.fin Answer Updated. Pl. check

Comment: @Leem.fin I updated answer with primitives type !!! Please check once you get time and accept answer it will help other SO user to resolve same kind of issue..

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
   NSArray *timearray = @[@"time:1474437948687,fajlsfj...",
        @"time:1474237943221, axsasdfd...",
        @"time:1474681430940, someother..."];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;

    sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@""
                                                 ascending:NO];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [timearray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSLog(@"sortedArray %@",sortedArray);
```

Output:

```
sortedArray (
        "time:1474681430940, someother...",
        "time:1474437948687,fajlsfj...",
        "time:1474237943221, axsasdfd..."
    )
```

Answer (score -3):

First of all it seems to be a good idea to transform the string into instances of an entity type that reflects the data in a key-value manner. Then you can sort it easily by using an instance of `NSSortDescriptor`:

```
NSSortDescriptor *timeSorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"time" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sorted = [myData sortedArrayUsingSortDescriptors:@[timeSorter]];
```

However, you can sort the array as is by using a more complex sort descriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor *timeSorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO comparator:
^(id one, id two )
{
  NSString *timestamp1 = [one compenentsSepartedByString:@","][0];
  timestamp1 = [timestamp1 substringFromIndex:5];
  NSString *timestamp2 = [two compenentsSepartedByString:@","][0];
  timestamp2 = [timestamp2 substringFromIndex:5];
  return [timestamp1 compare:timestamp2 options:NSNumericSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [timestamp1 length])];
}];
NSArray *sorted = [myData sortedArrayUsingSortDescriptors:@[timeSorter]];
```

Typed in Safari.